# How to load json data directly in an Angular Form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I get a form that I want to populate with data coming from a json file (later on, I think of using data from an API REST)

```
    <form [formGroup]="revenueForm" (ngSubmit)="revenueManager()">

  <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center" id="tauxOccupation">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 75%">
      <mat-label>Occupancy Rate</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="valueOccupancy"
             formControlName="tauxOccupation">%
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center" id="priceMaxChambresAppartement">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 75%">
      <mat-label>Max Fare of this type of room</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="number" min="0" max="500" step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="valueMax"
             formControlName="priceMaxChambresAppartement"> Valeur conseillée : {{products[4].priceMax}}
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
</form>
```

NOTE:

- The form is the same according to the type of room selected. In my case, 0 is the json line for single... to 4 for the appartment rooms.
- I had to use ngModel because I got to use 3 sliders and didn't think this through. I will have to reformat them to make the form completly reactive form
- Lastly, I don't understand why I can't display the value directly in the field but only below as an indication (ie below)
  [image: example of value only outside of the field]

I might have missed why I can't put the data directly in the field

Comment: I think this is not right approach to use formControl  and ngmodel for input.

Comment: @Abhishek, Yes, at first I used only a reactive form but due to a slider added, I had to compose with it. I am planning to change it to exclusevily reactive form as I was following a tutorial on the slider on material angular but they didn't plan it with reactive form

Comment: Three things are at play here.  1) The actual HTML values 2) The formcontrol values and 3) The model values.  Ideally you should be able to always access the model for the values.  But when using Form Controls instead of NgModel there is not two way binding support.  You are forced into the immutability model.  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-form-validation-patterns-5c8b. I steer away from formControl in favor of ngmodel due to two way binding.  My models are always current.

Comment: This means you can get rid of the formcontrols and the formgroup and stick with the ngmodel, but your internal model should contain all the properties, like this:  currentModelInstance.valueOccupancy, currentModelInstance.valueMax. etc. This is call containmnent and allows you to switch the content just by a new currentModelInstance.

Comment: @LucasClement, **NOT** use [(ngModel)] in a input you has formControlName. When you create the form, give the value you want to each FormControl. Generally you use a function that get a value and return a form group, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003106/angular-9-0-formgroup-and-formarray-remove-row-from-table/64004202#64004202 (note, it's for a more complex answer, but the function createGroup it's the same)

Comment: Thanks all (John Peters and Eliseo), I will switch back to strictly reactive forms. I think I got to review the basics of angular. I am a newbie on it. I am trying to make a loop for the formbuilder right now and I can't get behind the logic used